# Can you use "has" instead of "contains"?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style, redundancy

If I say:

The new ipad has a 4.5" lcd screen and a microUSB slot.

instead of:

The new ipad contains a 4.5" lcd screen and a microUSB slot.

Is it better or worse? Is "contains" necessary, am I losing some meaning by simply putting a broader "has".

Comment: I think everyone understands it either way but "has" is definitely the word you should take here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case "has" is certainly the preferred option.

"Contains" seems to indicate that something resides *inside* something else, or that something is an *ingredient* of something.

With electronic equipment the features the object has are being used by it, they are not simply inside (or in the case of a screen, they are actually on the outside.

> Milk *contains* fat.
>   This box *contains* my stamp collection.

But

> My car *has* leather seats.
>   My TV *has* an internet connection.

In the case of your iPad:

> The new iPad *has* a 4.5" screen.

Alternatively, since we can think of the iPad as "showing off" the really nice screen:

> The new iPad *sports* a 4.5" screen.

Off-topic, I'm not following these things very closely, but I have a 10" tablet. Is 4.5" very small for a tablet, or do you mean an iPhone?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is small, I just typed a random number :)